# ruby on rails app - html5 option tag dynamically generated with sqlite3 table records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, activerecord

I am attempting to create a security model with sqlite3.

This code is inside of the _form.html.erb file inside of ../views/users/

I have a user model & a user_level model ( admin, user, etc ).

```
rails generate scaffold user_level desc:string
rails generate scaffold user email:string password:string user_level:references
```

When creating/editing a 'user', i want to be able to select a 'user_level' value from the html5  tag.

I am getting a `undefined method`desc' for nil:NilClass` error when i try to view the page.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_level %><br />
    <select id="select_user_level">
      <%= @user_level.desc do |desc| %>
        <option value = "1"><%= desc %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
    <%= f.text_field :user_level %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_level, User::USER_LEVEL, :to_s :humanize %>
```

Then in the Model you should add an Array containing all possible user levels like this:

```
USER_LEVEL = ["admin", "mod", "user"]
```

Then it should work and you dont need @user_level anymore